# Can't compile properly with make

Tags: c, makefile, compilation

When I try to compile with `make` the program doesn't work, but compiling using `gcc` via shell works. The `make` doesn't give an error or anything, and works properly but only with one source file but doesn't work properly (playler.c), this is so strange that the IA of the enemy (represented with "(A)") works. And as I can see the display.c doesn't work also with the `make` command (the enemy should't have a trace).

When I compile with the shell command, I have to include .c instead of .h, but with make works normal with .h, example:

engine.c with shell command:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "./engine.h"
#include "./display.c"
#include "./enemy.c"
#include "./map.c"
#include "./player.c"
#include "../../config.h"
```

engine.c with make command:

```
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "./engine.h"
#include "./display.h"
#include "./enemy.h"
#include "./map.h"
#include "./player.h"
#include "../../config.h"
```

Shell:

```
gcc -lncurses src/main.c -o WeirdRpg
```

The makefile that i made first:

```
NAME=WeirdRpg
RM=rm -rf
CC=gcc
CLIBS= -lncurses
CFLAGS= -g -Wall -pedantic
SRC=src
OBJ=build/
OUT=build/$(NAME)

SOURCES=$(wildcard $(SRC)/*.c)
ENGINE=$(wildcard $(SRC)/engine/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst $(SRC)/%.c, $(OBJ)/%.o, $(SOURCES) $(ENGINE))

all: $(OUT)

$(OUT): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CLIBS) $^ -o $@

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
    mkdir -p "$(shell dirname "$@")"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(SRC) -c $< -o $@

$(OBJ)/%.o: $(SRC)/%.c
    mkdir -p "$(shell dirname "$@")"
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -I$(SRC) -c $< -o $@

debug: CFLAGS+=-DDEBUG
debug: build

.PHONY: clean

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ) $(OUT)
```

Makefile from a site:

```
TARGET_EXEC ?= WeirdRpg

BUILD_DIR ?= ./build
SRC_DIRS ?= ./src
CLIBS= -lncurses
CC=clang

SRCS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -name *.cpp -or -name *.c -or -name *.s)
OBJS := $(SRCS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)
DEPS := $(OBJS:.o=.d)

INC_DIRS := $(shell find $(SRC_DIRS) -type d)
INC_FLAGS := $(addprefix -I,$(INC_DIRS))

CPPFLAGS ?= $(INC_FLAGS) -MMD -MP

$(BUILD_DIR)/$(TARGET_EXEC): $(OBJS)
        $(CC) $(CLIBS) $(OBJS) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c
        $(MKDIR_P) $(dir $@)
        $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

.PHONY: clean

clean:
        $(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR)

-include $(DEPS)

MKDIR_P ?= mkdir -p
```

Result:

make command:

[image: make command]

gcc command:

[image: gcc command]

Source Code:

https://github.com/KisuYami/WeirdRPG

Comment: If you clean your build directory (remove object files etc.), and build again, take a close look at the output from the build. Does it do exactly what it's supposed to do? Does it run the correct commands with the correct arguments?

Comment: The rule for `$(BUILD_DIR)/%.c.o: %.c` in your makefile does not do what you probably think it does.  You've mixed the form for a suffix rule with the form for a pattern rule.  You've made a similar mangle here: `OBJS := $(SRCS:%=$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o)`, which happens to offset the other.

Comment: And as a general rule, ***never*** include source files using `#include`. Not even when building manually.

Comment: You're making a lot of use of the `?=` assignment operator, which in my experience is almost *never* used.  I had to look it up to even confirm that it was valid.  I don't think that's causing your problem, but you seem overall to have gone overboard with advanced and esoteric features of GNU `make` without pausing to become familiar with the form and toolset of standard `make`.

Comment: Already recompiled and cleanned build, and the makefile is sugested in another post(can't find now). And this issue happens with any makefile that use objects, and in every case i cleanned the objects folder and the final program(WeirdRpg) even manually.

Comment: Idk how to comment a comment here, about ?= i really don't know why, but am trying anything, like the same make files work in olthers projects, but in this the makefile just break some part of the code, that works normaly when copiling the mannualy.

Comment: When you have issues with makefiles it's often useful to pepper the makefile with a few well chosen `$(info ...)` statements.  Try `$(info SRCS=[$(SRCS)])` and `$(info OBJS=[$(OBJS)]` -- the output might not be what you expect.